# Pytest mock file write for arbitrary files

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm trying to mock the below code snippet out, but have been hitting a wall.

```
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b''.join(byte_data))
```

In the test where I'm trying to mock this out, I don't actually want a file to be written too. I actually don't even care if the file is opened.
There are multiple calls to `open` with arbitrary `file_path`. Ideally, this whole chuck would be mocked out.

I have tried using the `mock_open` helper, but not getting it to work.

In general I would like to just patch `builtins.open` and also whatever needs to be patched to patch the `f.write(b''.join(byte_data))` portion of the code.

Comment: Just mocking `builtins.open` should be sufficient, `f` would also be a mock, so there is no need to mock `write` separately . What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You have to patch `open()` in the module where it's used, not where it's defined.

Module `foo.py` with the implementation:

```py
def bar(file_path, byte_data):
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(b''.join(byte_data))
```

Tests in `test_foo.py`, using the `mocker` fixture from the [pytest-mock plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/):

```py
import foo

def test_foo(mocker):
    mocker.patch("foo.open")
    foo.bar("somefilepath", [b"a", b"b", b"c"])
```

After patching `open()`, open is a [`unittest.mock.MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) object.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open